# find coordinates of given element in Raphaël JS generated image

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am setting some elements to my canvas, and using Raphael JS to handle the drag and drop.

What I need to know, is how can I obtain the element that I am dragging's initial x/y positon in relation to the div (that has been set up to be used by Raphael) that its being dragged around in?

I would in jQuery of used offset - what is a simlar function to use in HTML5?

**EDIT**

Found it - solution is :

```
element.realPath[0][1]; //X Co-Ords
element.realPath[0][2]; //Y Co-Ords
```

Comment: How are you using RaphaelJS and canvas together?

Comment: Apologies, by canvas I mean the div that is set up to work with Raphael JS :)

Comment: Raphaël generates SVG, not HTML5 – please read the appropriate documentation. Which event are you using to catch the mouse movement – doesn't the event store the mouse position probably?

Comment: I didnt know you could do that! thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

Solution

```
element.realPath[0][1]; //X Co-Ords
element.realPath[0][2]; //Y Co-Ords
```